# tracking click event using jquery

Tags: jquery

i know how to track the click event on anchor tag when href attribute is directly assigned. but instead of assigning href attribute  if we give the destination link in onclick function.
or when we are loading ajax file how to track the destination url?

Comment: Explain track the destination URL. You can define where you want them to go to?

Comment: could you try rephrasing what you mean? It's not very clear what you mean by *tracking* the click event

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what your looking for but I'll give it a try do you mean something like this? When they click on the element it will redirect them?

**Post some clearer details and ill edit.**

```
var MyURL = 'http://ABCDEF.com' //Define MyURL
$('#MyElementID').click(function () { //Define the element ID that you click
    window.location = MyURL; //Tell it what to do e.g load MyURL
}
```

Then to figure out what the destination is

```
$('#MyElementID2').html(MyURL); //Display MyURL in Element
```

or Alert:

```
alert(MyURL); //Alert MyURL.
```